# Why can't DSolve find a solution for my system of ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

I want to find a basis for the set of solutions of the following system of ODEs.

```
DSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]/t - y[t], y'[t] == x[t] + y[t]/t}, {y[t], x[t]}, t]
```

I get very unexpected result when I evaluate the above expression. Mathematica returns my input.

Of course, I know the answer.

**Update**

From Wolfram Technical Support:

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I have confirmed that DSolve is not able to find the solution to the equation you provided. I found a workaround by introducing an arbitrary variable 'a' then setting a=-1 at the end of the calculation. This can be done as follows:
>
> `X[t_]:={x[t],y[t]}
>   A={{1/t,a},{-a,1/t}};
>   system=X'[t]==A.X[t];
>   sol=DSolve[system,{x,y},t]
>   sol/.{a-> -1}`
>
> DSolve should be able to sole the equation in the original form you provided. I will file a report with our developers regarding this issue. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.
>    **[CASE:3808703]**

Comment: Does the answer that you know work when t==0? When it can be justified, eliminating denominators seems to almost always give better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in version 11.1  Now `DSolve` can solve it directly

```
 $Version
```

11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)

```
 ClearAll[x,t,y];
 DSolve[{x'[t]==x[t]/t-y[t],y'[t]==x[t]+y[t]/t},{y[t],x[t]},t]

 {{x[t]->t C[1] Cos[t]-t C[2] Sin[t],y[t]->t C[2] Cos[t]+t C[1] Sin[t]}}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why this doesn't work. Until someone finds the reason, here is a workaround to solve the system of equations:

```
ode={x'[t] == x[t]/t - y[t], y'[t] == x[t] + y[t]/t}
```

Using the change of variables $x(t)=t X(t)$ and $y(t)=tY(t)$,

```
ode /. {x -> ((# X[#]) &), y -> ((# Y[#]) &)}
(* X[t] + t X'[t] == X[t] - t Y[t], Y[t] + t Y'[t] == t X[t] + Y[t] *)
```

which is now easily solved by `DSolve`:

```
DSolve[%, {X[t], Y[t]}, {t}]
(* X[t] -> C[1] Cos[t] - C[2] Sin[t], Y[t] -> C[2] Cos[t] + C[1] Sin[t] *)
```

Comment: I would read this post as a proof that there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the system of ODE's; the problem seems to be with MM, not with the equations themselves. I would be very happy if someone finds the reason for MM to dislike the equations in their initial form.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to solve in Mathematica.

\begin{align*}
x^{\prime}\left(  t\right)    & =\frac{x\left(  t\right)  }{t}-y\left(
t\right)  \\
y^{\prime}\left(  t\right)    & =x\left(  t\right)  -\frac{y\left(  t\right)
}{t}
\end{align*}

Write as

$$
\dot{X}=AX
$$

Where $A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{t} & -1\\
1 & \frac{-1}{t}
\end{pmatrix}
$. Let us assume the solution is $X\left(  t\right)  =X\left(  0\right)
e^{\int_{0}^{t}A\left(  \tau\right)  d\tau}$. However, this only works (since this is matrix time varying system) if $A$
commutes with $e^{\int_{0}^{t}A\left(  \tau\right)  d\tau}$. i.e. if
$$
A\left(  t\right)  e^{\int_{0}^{t}A\left(  \tau\right)  d\tau}=e^{\int_{0}
^{t}A\left(  \tau\right)  d\tau}A\left(  t\right)
$$

If it does not commute, things get little more complicated. We can check, using Mathematica, that it does indeed commute in this example, so we are lucky

```
(mat = {{1/t, -1}, {1, 1/t}}) // MatrixForm
(bmat = MatrixExp[Integrate[mat, t]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 mat.bmat == bmat.mat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore, we can ask Mathematica now to solve it, using `MatrixExp`

```
x0 = {c1, c2}; (*constant of integration*)
(sol = x0.bmat) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is the solution. First row is $x(t)$ and second row is $y(t)$.

Why did Mathematica not solve it? I do not know.